# Get two results without repeating preg_match and file_get_contents

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

I'm newbie to php

And I need to get two results from the same page. og:image and og:video

This my current code

```
preg_match('/property="og:video" content="(.*?)"/', file_get_contents($url), $matchesVideo);
preg_match('/property="og:image" content="(.*?)"/', file_get_contents($url), $matchesThumb);

$videoID = ($matchesVideo[1]) ? $matchesVideo[1] : false;
$videoThumb = ($matchesThumb[1]) ? $matchesThumb[1] : false;
```

Is there a way to execute the same operation without duplicating my code

Comment: Of course, assign the result of file_get_contents to a variable.

Comment: but you will have to do two times the preg_match, since it is not the same operation. but yeat, doing `$content = file_get_contents($url);` will save lot of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with having those two lines. What I would change though is the double call to `file_get_contents($url)`.

Just change it to:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/property="og:video" content="(.*?)"/', $html, $matchesVideo);
preg_match('/property="og:image" content="(.*?)"/', $html, $matchesThumb);
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the file contents to a variable, and if you want to run a single regular expression, you can opt for:

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('/property="og:(?P<type>video|image)" content="(?P<content>.*?)"/', $file, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $match['type'] ...
    $match['content'] ...
}
```

As @hakre points out, the first parenthesis pair is not needed:

> The first parenthesis pair uses the no capture modifier `?:`, it causes a match but is not stored

Capture groups use named subpatterns `?P<name>`, the second capture group establish any of the two words is a possible match `image|video`.

Comment: The first (non-matching) parenthesis pair looks superfluous to me. Group 0 will match anyway, subgroups will match anyway. It's just not needed so you could concentrate on explaining the namined subpaterns instead first talking about a non-matching group that's not needed ;)

Comment: I don't think so, a tag with different `type` might match the pattern

Comment: No, only the whole pattern can match. That is video or image and no other type. The group 0 is immanent, you don't need to explicitly create it (always the whole pattern, ideally use () as outer parenthesis instead of //). Try it out.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to execute the same operation without duplicating my code

There are always two ways to do that:

1. Buffer an execution result - instead of executing multiple times.
2. Encode the repetition - extract parameters from code.

In programming you normally make use of both. For example the buffering of the file I/O operation:

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($url);
```

And for the matching, you encode the repetition:

```
$match = function ($what) use ($buffer) {
    $pattern = sprintf('/property="og:%s" content="(.*?)"/', $what);
    $result  = preg_match($pattern, $buffer, $matches);
    return $result ? $matches[1] : NULL;
}

$match('video');
$match('image');
```

This is only exemplary to show what I meant. It depends a bit how much you want to do this, e.g. the later allows to replace the matching with a different implementation like using a HTML parser but you might find it too much code at the moment for what you need to do and only go with the buffering.

E.g. the following could be applicable as well:

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($url);
$mask   = '/property="og:%s" content="(.*?)"/';
preg_match(sprintf($mask, 'video'), $buffer, $matchesVideo);
preg_match(sprintf($mask, 'image'), $buffer, $matchesThumb);
```

Hope this helps.